# VideoJS not working on IE8 with WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html5-video, video.js

I am using VideoJS on my [web page](http://www.feliciasearcy.com/test-video-page-2) and it is working in FF19 and Chrome25, but does not work on IE8.

The console logs the following in IE8:

`Invalid argument. video.js?ver=3.5.1, line 21 character 32228`

...which is the following:

`this.el.removeChild(this.tag);`

I also made a [Test page](http://www.feliciasearcy.com/video/test_gift_video.html) which contained only the video and that works on all browsers, which makes me think something in my theme is interfering with the video... but why would this only be in IE8 and not other browsers?

Comment: Supports IE 9+ or flash: http://videojs.com/#section5. Perhaps a problem interacting with flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 8 can be extremely picky about how you close tags. My problems were fixed by running my files through the W3C validator (http://validator.w3.org/) and correcting any errors. In particular, pay attention to how you close your CSS include's as well as your `<script>` tags.

Comment: Well @Sam youtsey your answer wasn't exactly the problem but it did lead me to the solution! I was inserting the `<video>` into the WordPress editor on multiple lines, which caused various `<p>` to be opened and closed incorrectly, causing invalid markup.